# What is the life expectancy of Starman and his car?

Tags: spacex

What is the life expectancy of starman and his vehicle if they either reach mars, or somehow miss and remain in space?

Comment: The car never was "going to mars", and certainly isn't going there now.  The final burn put it on a course for the asteroid belt.  So, "miss and remain in space" is the only option.

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17196/58

Comment: @JPhi1618 I'm not sure what plane it is in, mightn't it crash sometime in the next one billion years?

Comment: This actually doesn't strike me as a duplicate, if the asker is referring to the orbit, rather than the object. There doesn't seem to be a question addressing how long the orbit will keep Starman in space. Spacex has said it will stay in space for millions to billions of years, but it might be useful to explain that. Though that information might be easily found elsewhere.